# Catch selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element and continue with the for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, exception

I want to catch the exception `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element` and if it does I want to continue with the for loop. How can I achieve this ?

For example : I'm looping and finding a number say x; if x is not present which is throwing this error, I want it to ignore the exception and continue with the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your for loop as well?

Here's what you could do.

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

for ele in my_list:
    try:
        do_something()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass  # you could also say continue if you don't want to execute the rest of the for loop
```